# Magento 2 create admin form input field as like tag input style

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-admin

We are creating some input field in magento backend as like mentioned in the below screenshot.

[image]

For achieving this i am putting required codes with ignoring basic steps of module and db field creation.Showing save logic and getting collection while edit form in admin.

Answer (score 0):

First of we need to put our code for add new form action layout.

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/view/adminhtml/layout/[Vendor_Name]_[Module_Name]_create.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>

        <css src="[Vendor_Name]_[Module_Name]/css/jquery.tagsinput.css" />

    </head>

    <update handle="styles"/>

    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">

            <uiComponent name="zipcode_form"/>

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="zipcode.tag" template="[Vendor_Name]_[Module_Name]::tag/zipcodeload.phtml" />

        </referenceContainer>

    </body>

</page>
```

Edit form xml code :

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/view/adminhtml/layout/[Module_Name]_[Controller_Name]_edit.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>

        <css src="[Vendor_Name]_[Module_Name]/css/jquery.tagsinput.css" />

    </head>

    <update handle="styles"/>

    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">

            <uiComponent name="zipcode_form"/>

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="zipcode.tag" template="[Vendor_Name]_[Module_Name]::tag/zipcodeload.phtml" />

        </referenceContainer>

    </body>

</page>
```

Phtml code to render field in tagging style :

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/view/adminhtml/templates/tag/zipcodeload.phtml**

```
<script>

    require(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function ($) {

        require(['[Vendor_Name]_[Module_Name]/js/jquery.tagsinput'], function(){


            function split(val) {

                return val.split(/,\s*/);

            }

            function extractLast(term) {

                return split(term).pop();

            }



            var intr = setInterval(function() {

                var $el = $('[name*="zip_code"]');//Here is our input field name

                if (!$el.length) {

                    return;

                }

                clearInterval(intr);


                var oAddTag = $.fn.addTag;

                $.fn.addTag = function() {

                    setTimeout(function(){

                        $el.change();

                    }, 500);


                    return oAddTag.apply(this, arguments);

                };


                var oRemoveTag = $.fn.removeTag;

                $.fn.removeTag = function() {

                    setTimeout(function(){

                        $el.change();

                    }, 500);


                    return oRemoveTag.apply(this, arguments);

                };


                $el.each(function () {


                    var $e = $(this);

                    var $tags = $e.tagsInput({

                        'height':'200px',

                        'width':'768px',

                        'interactive':true,

                        'defaultText':'Add zip code',

                        'removeWithBackspace' : true,

                        'minChars' : 2,

                        'maxChars' : 0,

                    });


                    var linkedTags = '';


                    for (var i=0; i<linkedTags.length;i++) {

                        if (!$tags.tagExist(linkedTags[i])) {

                            $tags.addTag(linkedTags[i]);

                        }

                    }


                    $('#' + $tags.attr('id') + '_tag').autocomplete({

                        source: function (request, response) {

                            var searchTag = extractLast(request.term);

                        },

                        'select': function( event, ui ) {

                            var tag = ui.item.label;

                            $tags.removeTag(tag);

                            $tags.addTag(tag);

                            return false;

                        }

                    });

                });

            }, 1000);

        })

    });

</script>
```

Admin Ui form input field append :

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/zipcode_form.xml**

```
<field name="restrict_region">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">

        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>

        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">

            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>

            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Please select State/Region to restrict </item>

            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>

            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>

            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>

            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>

            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">restrict_region</item>

            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>

            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>

            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>

            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>

            <item name="levelsVisibility" xsi:type="number">1</item>

            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>

            <item name="listens" xsi:type="array">

                <item name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData" xsi:type="string">setParsed</item>

            </item>

        </item>

    </argument>

</field>

<field name="zip_code">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">

        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">

            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>

            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Please enter zip code to restrict</item>

            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>

            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">zip_code</item>

            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">zip_code</item>

        </item>

    </argument>

</field>
```

Ui form input field CSS for tagging style :
**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/view/adminhtml/web/css/jquery.tagsinput.css**

```
div.tagsinput { border:1px solid #CCC; background: #FFF; padding:5px; width:300px; height:100px; overflow-y: auto;}

div.tagsinput span.tag { border: 1px solid #a79d95; -moz-border-radius:2px; -webkit-border-radius:2px; display: block; float: left; padding: 5px; text-decoration:none; background: #f5f5f5; color: #41362f; margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom:5px;font-family: helvetica;  font-size:13px;}

div.tagsinput span.tag > span {cursor: pointer;}

div.tagsinput span.tag a { font-weight: bold; color: #41362f; text-decoration:none; font-size: 11px;  }

div.tagsinput input { width:100px !important; margin:0px; font-family: helvetica; font-size: 13px; border:1px solid transparent; padding:5px; background: transparent; color: #000; outline:0px;  margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px; }

div.tagsinput div { display:block; float: left; } 

.tags_clear { clear: both; width: 100%; height: 0px; }

.not_valid {background: #FBD8DB !important; color: #90111A !important;}
```

Ui form tagsinput field required js plugin code :
**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/view/adminhtml/web/js/jquery.tagsinput.js**

```
/*

    jQuery Tags Input Plugin 1.3.3

    Copyright (c) 2011 XOXCO, Inc

    Documentation for this plugin lives here:
    http://xoxco.com/clickable/jquery-tags-input

    Licensed under the MIT license:
    http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

    ben@xoxco.com

*/

(function($) {

    var delimiter = new Array();
    var tags_callbacks = new Array();
    $.fn.doAutosize = function(o){
        var minWidth = $(this).data('minwidth'),
            maxWidth = $(this).data('maxwidth'),
            val = '',
            input = $(this),
            testSubject = $('#'+$(this).data('tester_id'));

        if (val === (val = input.val())) {return;}

        // Enter new content into testSubject
        var escaped = val.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/\s/g,' ').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        testSubject.html(escaped);
        // Calculate new width + whether to change
        var testerWidth = testSubject.width(),
            newWidth = (testerWidth + o.comfortZone) >= minWidth ? testerWidth + o.comfortZone : minWidth,
            currentWidth = input.width(),
            isValidWidthChange = (newWidth < currentWidth && newWidth >= minWidth)
                                 || (newWidth > minWidth && newWidth < maxWidth);

        // Animate width
        if (isValidWidthChange) {
            input.width(newWidth);
        }


  };
  $.fn.resetAutosize = function(options){
    // alert(JSON.stringify(options));
    var minWidth =  $(this).data('minwidth') || options.minInputWidth || $(this).width(),
        maxWidth = $(this).data('maxwidth') || options.maxInputWidth || ($(this).closest('.tagsinput').width() - options.inputPadding),
        val = '',
        input = $(this),
        testSubject = $('<tester/>').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: -9999,
            left: -9999,
            width: 'auto',
            fontSize: input.css('fontSize'),
            fontFamily: input.css('fontFamily'),
            fontWeight: input.css('fontWeight'),
            letterSpacing: input.css('letterSpacing'),
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
        }),
        testerId = $(this).attr('id')+'_autosize_tester';
    if(! $('#'+testerId).length > 0){
      testSubject.attr('id', testerId);
      testSubject.appendTo('body');
    }

    input.data('minwidth', minWidth);
    input.data('maxwidth', maxWidth);
    input.data('tester_id', testerId);
    input.css('width', minWidth);
  };

    $.fn.addTag = function(value,options) {
            options = jQuery.extend({focus:false,callback:true},options);
            this.each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                var tagslist = $(this).val().split(delimiter[id]);
                if (tagslist[0] == '') {
                    tagslist = new Array();
                }

                value = jQuery.trim(value);

                if (options.unique) {
                    var skipTag = $(this).tagExist(value);
                    if(skipTag == true) {
                        //Marks fake input as not_valid to let styling it
                        $('#'+id+'_tag').addClass('not_valid');
                    }
                } else {
                    var skipTag = false;
                }

                if (value !='' && skipTag != true) {
                    $('<span>').addClass('tag').append(
                        $('<span>').text(value).append('&nbsp;&nbsp;'),
                        $('<a>', {
                            href  : '#',
                            title : 'Removing tag',
                            text  : 'x'
                        }).click(function () {
                            return $('#' + id).removeTag(escape(value));
                        })
                    ).insertBefore('#' + id + '_addTag');

                    tagslist.push(value);

                    $('#'+id+'_tag').val('');
                    if (options.focus) {
                        $('#'+id+'_tag').focus();
                    } else {
                        $('#'+id+'_tag').blur();
                    }

                    $.fn.tagsInput.updateTagsField(this,tagslist);

                    if (options.callback && tags_callbacks[id] && tags_callbacks[id]['onAddTag']) {
                        var f = tags_callbacks[id]['onAddTag'];
                        f.call(this, value);
                    }
                    if(tags_callbacks[id] && tags_callbacks[id]['onChange'])
                    {
                        var i = tagslist.length;
                        var f = tags_callbacks[id]['onChange'];
                        f.call(this, $(this), tagslist[i-1]);
                    }
                }

            });

            return false;
        };

    $.fn.removeTag = function(value) {
            value = unescape(value);
            this.each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

                var old = $(this).val().split(delimiter[id]);

                $('#'+id+'_tagsinput .tag').remove();
                str = '';
                for (i=0; i< old.length; i++) {
                    if (old[i]!=value) {
                        str = str + delimiter[id] +old[i];
                    }
                }

                $.fn.tagsInput.importTags(this,str);

                if (tags_callbacks[id] && tags_callbacks[id]['onRemoveTag']) {
                    var f = tags_callbacks[id]['onRemoveTag'];
                    f.call(this, value);
                }
            });

            return false;
        };

    $.fn.tagExist = function(val) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var tagslist = $(this).val().split(delimiter[id]);
        return (jQuery.inArray(val, tagslist) >= 0); //true when tag exists, false when not
    };

   // clear all existing tags and import new ones from a string
   $.fn.importTags = function(str) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#'+id+'_tagsinput .tag').remove();
      $.fn.tagsInput.importTags(this,str);
   }

    $.fn.tagsInput = function(options) {
    var settings = jQuery.extend({
      interactive:true,
      defaultText:'add a tag',
      minChars:0,
      width:'300px',
      height:'100px',
      autocomplete: {selectFirst: false },
      hide:true,
      delimiter: ',',
      unique:true,
      removeWithBackspace:true,
      placeholderColor:'#666666',
      autosize: true,
      comfortZone: 20,
      inputPadding: 6*2
    },options);

        var uniqueIdCounter = 0;

        this.each(function() {
         // If we have already initialized the field, do not do it again
         if (typeof $(this).attr('data-tagsinput-init') !== 'undefined') {
            return;
         }

         // Mark the field as having been initialized
         $(this).attr('data-tagsinput-init', true);

            if (settings.hide) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (!id || delimiter[$(this).attr('id')]) {
                id = $(this).attr('id', 'tags' + new Date().getTime() + (uniqueIdCounter++)).attr('id');
            }

            var data = jQuery.extend({
                pid:id,
                real_input: '#'+id,
                holder: '#'+id+'_tagsinput',
                input_wrapper: '#'+id+'_addTag',
                fake_input: '#'+id+'_tag'
            },settings);

            delimiter[id] = data.delimiter;

            if (settings.onAddTag || settings.onRemoveTag || settings.onChange) {
                tags_callbacks[id] = new Array();
                tags_callbacks[id]['onAddTag'] = settings.onAddTag;
                tags_callbacks[id]['onRemoveTag'] = settings.onRemoveTag;
                tags_callbacks[id]['onChange'] = settings.onChange;
            }

            var markup = '<div id="'+id+'_tagsinput" class="tagsinput"><div id="'+id+'_addTag">';

            if (settings.interactive) {
                markup = markup + '<input id="'+id+'_tag" value="" data-default="'+settings.defaultText+'" />';
            }

            markup = markup + '</div><div class="tags_clear"></div></div>';

            $(markup).insertAfter(this);

            $(data.holder).css('width',settings.width);
            $(data.holder).css('min-height',settings.height);
            $(data.holder).css('height',settings.height);

            if ($(data.real_input).val()!='') {
                $.fn.tagsInput.importTags($(data.real_input),$(data.real_input).val());
            }
            if (settings.interactive) {
                $(data.fake_input).val($(data.fake_input).attr('data-default'));
                $(data.fake_input).css('color',settings.placeholderColor);
                $(data.fake_input).resetAutosize(settings);

                $(data.holder).bind('click',data,function(event) {
                    $(event.data.fake_input).focus();
                });

                $(data.fake_input).bind('focus',data,function(event) {
                    if ($(event.data.fake_input).val()==$(event.data.fake_input).attr('data-default')) {
                        $(event.data.fake_input).val('');
                    }
                    $(event.data.fake_input).css('color','#000000');
                });

                if (settings.autocomplete_url != undefined) {
                    autocomplete_options = {source: settings.autocomplete_url};
                    for (attrname in settings.autocomplete) {
                        autocomplete_options[attrname] = settings.autocomplete[attrname];
                    }

                    if (jQuery.Autocompleter !== undefined) {
                        $(data.fake_input).autocomplete(settings.autocomplete_url, settings.autocomplete);
                        $(data.fake_input).bind('result',data,function(event,data,formatted) {
                            if (data) {
                                $('#'+id).addTag(data[0] + "",{focus:true,unique:(settings.unique)});
                            }
                        });
                    } else if (jQuery.ui.autocomplete !== undefined) {
                        $(data.fake_input).autocomplete(autocomplete_options);
                        $(data.fake_input).bind('autocompleteselect',data,function(event,ui) {
                            $(event.data.real_input).addTag(ui.item.value,{focus:true,unique:(settings.unique)});
                            return false;
                        });
                    }


                } else {
                        // if a user tabs out of the field, create a new tag
                        // this is only available if autocomplete is not used.
                        $(data.fake_input).bind('blur',data,function(event) {
                            var d = $(this).attr('data-default');
                            if ($(event.data.fake_input).val()!='' && $(event.data.fake_input).val()!=d) {
                                if( (event.data.minChars <= $(event.data.fake_input).val().length) && (!event.data.maxChars || (event.data.maxChars >= $(event.data.fake_input).val().length)) )
                                    $(event.data.real_input).addTag($(event.data.fake_input).val(),{focus:true,unique:(settings.unique)});
                            } else {
                                $(event.data.fake_input).val($(event.data.fake_input).attr('data-default'));
                                $(event.data.fake_input).css('color',settings.placeholderColor);
                            }
                            return false;
                        });

                }
                // if user types a default delimiter like comma,semicolon and then create a new tag
                $(data.fake_input).bind('keypress',data,function(event) {
                    if (_checkDelimiter(event)) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        if( (event.data.minChars <= $(event.data.fake_input).val().length) && (!event.data.maxChars || (event.data.maxChars >= $(event.data.fake_input).val().length)) )
                            $(event.data.real_input).addTag($(event.data.fake_input).val(),{focus:true,unique:(settings.unique)});
                        $(event.data.fake_input).resetAutosize(settings);
                        return false;
                    } else if (event.data.autosize) {
                        $(event.data.fake_input).doAutosize(settings);

                    }
                });
                //Delete last tag on backspace
                // data.removeWithBackspace && $(data.fake_input).bind('keydown', function(event)
                // {
                //  if(event.keyCode == 8 && $(this).val() == '')
                //  {
                //       event.preventDefault();
                //       var last_tag = $(this).closest('.tagsinput').find('.tag:last').text();
                //       var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/_tag$/, '');
                //       last_tag = last_tag.replace(/[\s]+x$/, '');
                //       $('#' + id).removeTag(escape(last_tag));
                //       $(this).trigger('focus');
                //  }
                // });
                // $(data.fake_input).blur();

                //Removes the not_valid class when user changes the value of the fake input
                if(data.unique) {
                    $(data.fake_input).keydown(function(event){
                        if(event.keyCode == 8 || String.fromCharCode(event.which).match(/\w+|[áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ,/]+/)) {
                            $(this).removeClass('not_valid');
                        }
                    });
                }
            } // if settings.interactive
        });

        return this;

    };

    $.fn.tagsInput.updateTagsField = function(obj,tagslist) {
        var id = $(obj).attr('id');
        $(obj).val(tagslist.join(delimiter[id]));
    };

    $.fn.tagsInput.importTags = function(obj,val) {
        $(obj).val('');
        var id = $(obj).attr('id');
        var tags = val.split(delimiter[id]);
        for (i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
            $(obj).addTag(tags[i],{focus:false,callback:false});
        }
        if(tags_callbacks[id] && tags_callbacks[id]['onChange'])
        {
            var f = tags_callbacks[id]['onChange'];
            f.call(obj, obj, tags[i]);
        }
    };

   /**
     * check delimiter Array
     * @param event
     * @returns {boolean}
     * @private
     */
   var _checkDelimiter = function(event){
      var found = false;
      if (event.which == 13) {
         return true;
      }

      if (typeof event.data.delimiter === 'string') {
         if (event.which == event.data.delimiter.charCodeAt(0)) {
            found = true;
         }
      } else {
         $.each(event.data.delimiter, function(index, delimiter) {
            if (event.which == delimiter.charCodeAt(0)) {
               found = true;
            }
         });
      }

      return found;
   }
})(jQuery);
```

Need to add this code in your form edit data provider to get region list getData function foreach loop here is just logic :

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Model/[Module_Name]/DataProvider.php**

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemdata = $item->getData();
        if (isset($itemdata['restrict_region'])

            && !empty($itemdata['restrict_region'])

        ) {

            $itemdata['restrict_region'] = explode(',', $itemdata['restrict_region']);

        }
    }
    return $itemdata;
```

Save Data in database by putting this code in your existing save functionality :

**app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Controller/Adminhtml/[Module_Name]/Save.php**

```
if (isset($data['restrict_region']) && !empty($data['restrict_region'])) {

        $data['restrict_region'] = implode(',', $data['restrict_region']);

    } else {

        $data['restrict_region'] = '';
        
    }
```